# Show element div collapse when click on map for `getFeatureInfoUrl`

Tags: openlayers, popup, overlay

I have a `slide toggle` that slides from right to left. I want when `getFeatureInfoUrl` is activated the result will be displayed in `slide toggle` and `slide toggle` automatically open. Now i was able to get the result to show in `slide toggle` but it doesn't open automatically.

How to make `slide toggle` automatically open when `getFeatureInfoUrl` is activated.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.1.0/ol/ol.css" />
    
    <!-- map -->
    <div id="map" class="map">
       <div id="gmap" class="fill"></div>
       <div id="olmap" class="fill"></div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- slide toggle -->
    <div class="willSlide" id='content'>
        <span style="width: 100%;" id="info">&nbsp;</span>
        <span style="width: 100%;" id="info_qpk"></span>
        <span style="width: 100%;" id="span_search"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="willSlide" id='btn'>
        <span class="click">open</span>
        <span class="expandedTxt">close</span>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.1.0/ol/dist/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB41DRUbKWJHPxaFjMAwdrzWzbVKartNGg&callback=initMap&v=weekly" defer></script>
<!-- jquery api-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<!--JS for slide toggle-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var easing = 1 //enable or disable easing | 0 or 1
  var animation_speed = 500 //ms
      
  var slider_width = $('#content').width();//get width automaticly
  $('#btn').click(function() 
  {
    //check if slider is collapsed
    var is_collapsed = $(this).css("margin-right") == slider_width+"px" && !$(this).is(':animated');
      
    //minus margin or positive margin
    var sign = (is_collapsed) ? '-' : '+'; 
    
      if(!$(this).is(':animated')) //prevent double margin on double click
      {
        if(easing) $('.willSlide').animate({"margin-right": sign+'='+slider_width},animation_speed);
        else $('.willSlide').animate({"margin-right": sign+'='+slider_width},animation_speed);
      }
     //if you need you can add class when expanded
      (is_collapsed) ? $('.willSlide').removeClass('expanded') : $('.willSlide').addClass('expanded');

  });
 });     
</script>
```

**JS for getFeatureInfoUrl**

```
function initMap() {
    var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      keyboardShortcuts: false,
      draggable: false,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
      scrollwheel: false,
      streetViewControl: false
    });

    var view = new ol.View({
      maxZoom: 21
    });
    
    function sync() {
      var center = ol.proj.transform(view.getCenter(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
      gmap.moveCamera({
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(center[1], center[0]),
        zoom: view.getZoom()
      });
    }
    
    view.on(['change:center', 'change:resolution'], sync);

    var olMapDiv = document.getElementById('olmap');
    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: olMapDiv,
      view: view
    });
    view.setCenter([0, 0]);
    view.setZoom(1);
    sync();

    olMapDiv.parentNode.removeChild(olMapDiv);
    gmap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(olMapDiv);
    
    var neLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
            // view: new ol.View({
            // projection: 'EPSG:4326'
            // }),
            source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
                params: {LAYERS: 'ne:ne', 'TILED': true},
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                ratio: 1,
            }),
            visible: true
        });
        map.addLayer(neLayer)
    
    var content = document.getElementById('info');
    map.on('click', function (evt) {
        content.innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
        var url = neLayer.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate,
            viewResolution,
            'EPSG:3857',
            {
                'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                'propertyName': 'admin,type',
            },
        );
        if (url) {
            $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                var feature = data.features[0];
                var props = feature.properties;
                content.innerHTML = 
                "<h3>Admin : </h5><p>" +  props.admin + "</p>"
                +"<h3>Yype : </h5><p>" + props.type + "</p>"
                // overlayPopup.show(content.innerHTML);
                // console.log(props);
            })
        }
    });
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

[LINK DEMO WITH JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bzgprah3/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to open slider when `getFeatureInfoUrl` is activated would be to define button click processing function as standalone function `slideToggle()`, which opens/closes slider and also sets global variable `is_collapsed` accordingly.

When `getFeatureInfoUrl` is activated, `is_collapsed` is then checked and `slideToggle()` called if necessary.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
var easing = 1;
var animation_speed = 500;      
var slider_width;
var is_collapsed = true;

function slideToggle() {
  is_collapsed = $('#btn').css("margin-right") == slider_width+"px" && !$('#btn').is(':animated');
  var sign = (is_collapsed) ? '-' : '+'; 
  if (!$('#btn').is(':animated')) {
    if(easing) $('.willSlide').animate({"margin-right": sign+'='+slider_width},animation_speed);
    else $('.willSlide').animate({"margin-right": sign+'='+slider_width},animation_speed);
  }
  (is_collapsed) ? $('.willSlide').removeClass('expanded') : $('.willSlide').addClass('expanded');
}
  
$(document).ready(function() {     
  slider_width = $('#content').width();//get width automaticly
  $('#btn').click(sidenavToggle);
 });     

map.on('click', function (evt) {
    content.innerHTML = '';
    var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
    var url = neLayer.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate,
      viewResolution,
      'EPSG:3857',
      {
          'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
          'propertyName': 'admin,type',
      },
    );
    if (url) {
      $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        var feature = data.features[0];
        var props = feature.properties;
        content.innerHTML = 
        "<h3>Admin : </h5><p>" +  props.admin + "</p>"
        +"<h3>Yype : </h5><p>" + props.type + "</p>"
        if (is_collapsed) slideToggle();
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: Wonderful. It works perfectly and so clean. Thanks you a lot.